# Parent-Child TreeView in Javascript from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, treeview

I want to create an array of objects. And each object may again have an array of objects from a JSON file. Each object in a JSOn has a parent_id which tells to which id it belongs to.

```
"data":[
        {
            "id":"node_0",
            "intentName":"pdf"
            "parent_id":"-1"
        },
        {
            "id":"node_2",
            "intentName":"Key Leadership",
            "parent_id":"node_0"
        },
        {
            "id":"node_3",
            "intentName":"Financial Results",
            "parent_id":"node_0"
        },
        {
            "id":"node_1",
            "intentName":"Business Summary",
            "parent_id":"node_0"
        },
        {
            "id":"node_7",
            "intentName":"Key Strategy",
            "parent_id":"node_1"
        },
        {
            "id":"node_34",
            "intentName":"CompanyInReport",
            "parent_id":"node_1"
        },
        {
            "id":"node_36",
            "intentName":"Operating Locations",
            "parent_id":"node_0"
        }]
```

This is the JSON file which has parent_id(-1 represents root parent and other represents its parent id). I want to create an array like below dynamically on startup.

```
menuItems = [
  {
    title: 'Key Leadership'
  },
  {
    title: 'Financial Results'
  },
  {
    title: 'Business Summary',
    values: [
      { title: 'Key Strategy'},
      { title: 'CompanyInReport'}
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Operating Locations'
  }]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you get an error in your code? please add error and code to the question.

Comment: use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I'm just unable to understand the logic to create such tree structure. @NinaScholz

Comment: @NinaScholz  First of all Thanks for the quick answer. Just out of curiosity, what if there is one more level of hierarchy i want in the same code.
{
            "id":"node_35",
            "intentName":"Annual Report",
            "parent_id":"node_34"
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a tree by using not only the node information `id`, but `parent_id` as well and assign the node information to the node and the parent infomation to the parent node.

This leads to a tree structure by taking nodes in arbitrary order.

As result take only the values of the wanted parent node, in this case `"node_0"`.

```js
var data = [{ id: "node_0", intentName: "pdf", parent_id: "-1" }, { id: "node_2", intentName: "Key Leadership", parent_id: "node_0" }, { id: "node_3", intentName: "Financial Results", parent_id: "node_0" }, { id: "node_1", intentName: "Business Summary", parent_id: "node_0" }, { id: "node_7", intentName: "Key Strategy", parent_id: "node_1" }, { id: "node_34", intentName: "CompanyInReport", parent_id: "node_1" }, { id: "node_36", intentName: "Operating Locations", parent_id: "node_0" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};

        data.forEach(({ id, intentName: title, parent_id }) => {
            Object.assign(o[id] = o[id] || {}, { title });
            o[parent_id] = o[parent_id] || {};
            o[parent_id].values = o[parent_id].values || [];
            o[parent_id].values.push(o[id]);
        });

        return o[root].values;
    }(data, 'node_0');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks alot @NinaScholz . I was trying this since long & its working great now. Thanks :)